# jQuery AJAX JSONP error "Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I'm trying to make a cross domain **JSONP** call in Chrome, but the I keep getting back **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"**
I've tried: changing the response content type, setting xhr headers, JSON.stringify, just about most of the solutions offered on here but nothing worked so far :-(

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {
                    apikey: "*",
                    resource: "http://www.1001freefonts.com/font/BaroqueScript.zip"
                },
                jsonp: false,
                jsonpCallback: receive,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log("Data retrieved: " + data);
                }
            }).done(function () {
                console.log('I think we are done here');
            })
        .error(function (e) {
            console.log(arguments);
            console.log('something went funny here');
        })
        .complete(function (xhr, status) {

            console.log("complete");
        if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
            console.log('error');
        }
        else {
            console.log("data found:" + xhr.responseText);
            //...
        }
    });
    });

    function receive(saveData) {
        if (saveData == null) {
            console.log("DATA IS UNDEFINED!");  // displays every time
        }
        console.log("Success is " + saveData);  // 'Success is undefined'
    }
```

In the debugger I can see the response

```
{"permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/url/b5b546fdbb49a2258e951c5e568a52655c65ac56112e39d15af0954a53b36772/analysis/1360339512/", "url": "http://www.1001freefonts.com/font/BaroqueScript.zip", "response_code": 1, "scan_date": "2013-02-08 16:05:12", "scan_id": "b5b546fdbb49a2258e951c5e568a52655c65ac56112e39d15af0954a53b36772-1360339512", "verbose_msg": "Scan finished, scan information embedded in this object", "filescan_id": "b7e13c0242e9690aba1f3da4b73d9c2e99a9b7fd03f542b55e694a34aaf9eca8-1360339519", "positives": 0, "total": 35, "scans": {"CLEAN MX": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "MalwarePatrol": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "ZDB Zeus": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "K7AntiVirus": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Quttera": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Yandex Safebrowsing": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "MalwareDomainList": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "ZeusTracker": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "zvelo": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Google Safebrowsing": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "BitDefender": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Opera": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "G-Data": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "C-SIRT": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Sucuri SiteCheck": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "VX Vault": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "ADMINUSLabs": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "SCUMWARE.org": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Dr.Web": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "AlienVault": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Malc0de Database": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "SpyEyeTracker": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Phishtank": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Avira": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Antiy-AVL": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Comodo Site Inspector": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "Malekal": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "ESET": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "SecureBrain": {"detected": false, "result": "unrated site"}, "Netcraft": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "ParetoLogic": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}, "URLQuery": {"detected": false, "result": "unrated site"}, "Wepawet": {"detected": false, "result": "unrated site"}, "Minotaur": {"detected": false, "result": "clean site"}}}
```

I've verified it on http://jsonlint.com/ and it shows that it's a valid JSON.

Here are the Response Headers

```
cache-control:no-cache
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:695
content-type:application/json
date:Wed, 13 Feb 2013 12:00:33 GMT
server:Google Frontend
status:200 OK
vary:Accept-Encoding
version:HTTP/1.1
```

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: For JSONP you need a functionwrapper. A Plain JSON Object is no valid JSONP Response. Is the server actually capable of serving JSONP-Responses?

Comment: Also `dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: false` does not look correct.

Comment: @Christoph Re `dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: false` they are correct, check out the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Christoph after further checking it seems the server can only send back JSON but not JSONP. I need to figure out to convert the response.

Comment: Further explanation for the readers
JSON header is `content-type:application/json`
JSONP header should be like this `Content-Type:application/javascript`

Comment: if you receive valid json, than you don't need to use JSONP and can work with the json data directly. (Since they seem to set the origin header accordingly)

Comment: @Christoph this is where I'm stuck because it keeps throwing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" and I can't access the actual response.

Comment: A plain JSON-request should work here. remove the jsonp stuff and change to the datatype to json instead.

Comment: @Christoph I tried, and this is when I get Cross-Domain error.

Comment: **Further update:** I can see that the status code is 200, it's not returning back an error.
The JSON object is in the Header response, I'm just not able to access it.

Answer (score 3):

After thorough testing, it was evident that it's not possible to capture the JSON object results when ajax is expecting JSONP in return (due to cross-domain restrictions). Even though the response status = 200.

I've been testing using jQuery AJAX calls, in attempt to see if the result can still be captured - despite there's Parsing Error thrown by the browser - but it didn't seem that's possible. It looks like that the Response Text arrives in the header after JS work is completed.

As @Florian F. @Likwid_T @Christoph have suggested above, a server-side script is definitely required to make it working properly. Other developers seem to be keen on using a proxy written in C# as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP doesn't work out of the box.

JSONP bypasses the cross-domain restriction by loading the result in a script tag.

Basically, your server has to be JSONP-enabled.

Do whatever needs to be done on your server side then right before sending the response :

1. Check if the request has "_callback" set
2. If set, wrap your content with the value of _callback.
3. Send your data

Code example in PHP :

```
$responseString = '{"smthing":"val","smthingelse":"val2"}';
if (isset($_REQUEST['_callback'])) {
    $responseString = $_REQUEST['_callback'] . '(' . $responseString . ');';
}
```

It'll execute your 'done' anonymous function with the right arguments. (JQuery handles everything else)

Comment: what makes you think, he can modify the server? If he's doing a crossdomain request it's very likely he is not controlling this.

Comment: Cause it's the only solution as is. Crossdomain is only useful when you control the server, or if the server accepts it itself. Next solution is to build a proxy on your own domain that'll forward the request to the webservice.

Comment: @FlorianF. Christoph is right, I don't have control over the server. My project is restricted to JS only.

Comment: @Eric Then what about a proxy on your own server ?

Comment: @FlorianF. It would've made life easier, unfortunately the code has to run as an extension. It's all JS.

Comment: @Eric No solution then. Or none i know of.

Comment: @FlorianF. I've been checking out older posts on here and I found that older versions of jQuery had $.httpdata that normally stores the data returned by the HTTP request.
I'm trying to get it to work with my current work, though I'm using version 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Christoph is right you need to encase your answer in your callback function, in your case at the end of the PHP file:

```
echo $_GET['receive'] . '(' . json_encode($yourResultObject) . ');';
```

or if you need a more complex object

```
echo $_GET['receive'] . '(' . json_encode(array(name1 => object1, name2 => object2, name3 => object3)) . ');';
```

You might have to tweak a bit, but basically whenever I get **Unexpected token** is almost always a syntax error that makes jQuery not get my callback function.

Comment: he doesn't have control over the serverside I think. Else in most cases you don't have to do a crossdomain request.

Comment: @Likwid_T unfortunately no server-side script can be involved. It'll have to remain JS.
Is it possible to apply the same manipulation in JS?
My callback function is not receiving the data, even though I can see in the response header the JSON object result returned.

Comment: Wait I just re-read: you're getting the data from the server in the response? {"permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/url/b5b546fdbb49a2258e951c5e568a52655c65ac56112e39d15af0954a53b36772... etc? Is that correct?

Comment: What's happens if you console.log(data["permalink"]);